# Pattern for sharing a large amount of data between the web application and a backend service in a Service Oriented Application

Tags: web-services, rest, design-patterns, soa, distributed-system

I have a web application which performs CRUD operations on a database. At times, I have to run a backend job to do a fair amount of number crunching/analytics on this data. This backend job will be written as a different service in a concurrent language, which will be independent of the main web application.

But actually sharing the DB between the 2 applications is probably not a best practice as it will lead to tight coupling. What is the right pattern to use here? Since this data might amount to millions of DB rows, I'm not sure using a message queue / REST APIs would be the best way to go.

This is perhaps a very common scenario and many companies/devs have already solved this problem. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it would seem that the background job does not modify state of database.

Simplest way to avoid performance hit on main application, while there is a background job running, is to take **database dump** and perform analysis on that dump.

Comment: The state of the data has to be consistent across both the services, since its not exactly analytics, rather it's some distributed calculations for financial data. But the service will only read and not modify the DB, modifying the DB happens exclusively via the web application. Is maintaining a real time replica DB the best approach to go with here?

Comment: This is what we did in our scenario. For us it was alright to not have 'perfect' real time analysis. How long does it take anyway to analyse data ? Are there any measurements done showing how it affects the system? Ideally job would be fired at the time when there is least activity. There is also no need to have real time replica for analysis, simply take snapshot (dump) before job is triggered.